# Can the web app manifest store properties which are not defined in the documentation?

Tags: manifest, progressive-web-apps

Can the Web app manifest be used to store properties that are not defined in the Documentation and/or not required by the PWA while launching.

This property might be something like a file location.

Also if it is possible how do I extract the properties from my Web manifest file.

Comment: Have you checked the usage of [webpack-pwa-manifest library](https://github.com/arthurbergmz/webpack-pwa-manifest/blob/master/README.md) in github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add in extra properties in the JSON file if you find that helpful. I am not sure that there's an advantage to doing that vs. storing that extra metadata in a standalone JSON file, though.

If you wanted to access those extra properties at runtime using JavaScript, you can do it via:

```
async function getManifestProperty(propertyName) {
  const link = document.head.querySelector('link[rel="manifest"]')
  if (link) {
    const response = await fetch(link.href);
    const json = await response.json();
    return json[propertyName];
  }
}
```